# Using Java and sales report to create number of sales in one day

Tags: java

I have quite a bit of experience with Java, but have rarely had to work with any type of inventory management systems, sales reports, and that kind of thing.  I'm working on a project where I have an excel report file of sales for the past year.  I can read this and find the information I need just fine, but I can't figure out how to get the number of sales for a particular item (SKU) each day without using a bunch of nested for loops.  I know there has to be an easier way, but I can't think of one at the moment.

For example, there's a bunch of information on 30,000 items that have sold over the past year.  I have created an array of 'Item' objects that pulls and sets string values for 'sku' and 'timestamp' (when the purchase was made).

Now I have to cycle through this and check how many items were sold each day, but I'm not for sure what the best way of doing this is.

My Item array could look like this:

```
//item[0] ; sku="AKD123"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
//item[1] ; sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
//item[2] ; sku="PIK383"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
//item[3] ; sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
```

There are about a million other items in this array, but from this, you can see that AKD123 sold 1, REN134 sold 2, PIK383 sold 1.  I'm not for sure how to get this output.    There has to be some sort of array method that can help me sort this in to day figures, but that may cause another problem because if a particular sku sold 0 units on 2012-02-01 then it wouldn't show up on the excel report.  I also don't know how many different skus there will be on a given report, so that's troubling me as well.

Code would be fantastic, but even a recommendation on what I need to search for would be great.  I feel like I should already know how to do this, but I'm lacking sleep and haven't been able to figure it out for the past 2 hours without VERY time consuming nested for loops, so I decided to turn to the community.

Thanks guys.

Comment: You could create a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` which holds the values of `<timestamp, <sku, frequency>>` where each timestamp is a different day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use Map object where you iterate over the array (or better dont use array , directly populate the map) where key can be concatenation of sku and date and value would be the count. So if you want to know how many items of sku  "REN134" was sold on "2012-02-01", check for the value against the key "REN134-2012-02-01"

If the requirement is to find out how many items if "REN134" was sold throughout , a map with key as sku and value as the count needs to be constructed.

Let me know if any special condition needs to be addressed, as most of such things can be addressed by using maps.

--
Peace.
Sanket Raut

Comment: Awesome!  I haven't really used maps much being mainly a game dev, but this definitely will help complete this project. So would I use Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> ? and when reading through the excel file, use mapObj.put(sku, otherMap.put(timestamp, othermap.get(stock)+1))  or something like that?  I haven't actually looked into maps, but I'm assuming its something like that?

Comment: depending on your report information , similar data-structures can be designed.. but why do you want to make such a map mapObj.put(sku, otherMap.put(timestamp, othermap.get(stock)+1))?? simple map wont suffice your need?